# Stasis Leak: Why didn't Lister save Peterson

Tags: time-travel, red-dwarf

In series 2, episode 4 of Red Dwarf, Stasis Leak, the post-apocalypse crew find a way to travel back in time to the Dwarf before the crew was wiped out and Lister resolves to freeze Kristine Kochanski in a stasis booth so he can live with her on the empty ship.

The episode ends with Lister discovering Kochanski is married to a (presumably alternative) future Lister, he is not able to take her with him to the future.

It's also established in the same episode that Lister really misses his drinking buddy, Olaf Peterson. He's thrilled to meet him, alive and well, in the past.

The question is this, after finding out that he can not save Kochanski from the fatal leak that wiped out the crew, why didn't Lister try to save Petersen (or one of his other buddies such as Chen or Selby) from the event instead?

Bonus question: Why didn't he try to stop the fatal event, either?

Comment: Because he's a smeghead. Next question.

Comment: I love how that's the generic answer to each and every Red Dwarf related question.

Comment: There are so many out of universe inconsistencies which the smeghead answer neatly covers in-universe.

Comment: Aren't people turned into dust when they try to travel through the timehole? Or is that a different episode?

Comment: It's established that they could put someone in to the stasis compartment to survive in the same way Lister did.

Comment: @AJFaraday In which case Rimmer ruins things by trying to put himself in the statis pod. Doesn't it end with a joke, rather than a plot resolution?

Comment: It does, yes. Although that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @AJFaraday No it doesn't. I'm afraid that *Red Dwarf* doesn't really play by any rules, even it's own.

Comment: @AJFaraday - I felt my answer was nicely comprehensive (albeit brief). Is there anything else you wanted me to address before considering an acceptance?

Comment: I'm not sure this would be enough to make Lister choose a life in the company of Rimmer, Holly and The Cat. With all the issues that brings him. Why would he listen to Future Rimmer?

Comment: @Richard perhaps some questions in life are best left in-answered.

Comment: @AJFaraday - He wouldn't listen to Future/Rimmer but her certainly trusts Future/Lister, especially if the course of action leads to him getting Kochanski back.

Comment: @Richaed I meant Future Lister. Texting on the go. And how would Future Lister know that the presence of Petersen would prevent the Marriage of Kochanski?

Answer (score 3):

**Because his future self [told him not to](http://www.clivebanks.co.uk/Red%20Dwarf/Stasisleak.htm)**

> **LISTER:** *So, listen. What do I do now?*
>
> **FUTURE LISTER:** *Go back to where you came from and wait for five years.*